# use laravel query with DataTable

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

I tried to initialise a DataTable with data which comes from a database via this query:

```
public function qryUsers()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('name')
            ->get();
        return $users;
    }
```

javascript:

```
    function loadTable() {
                $.getJSON('/admin/users3/qryUsers')
                    .done(function (data) {
                        console.log('data', data);
                        $('#table_id').DataTable({
                            "ajax": data,
                            "columns": [
                                {"data": "id"},
                                {"data": "name"},
                                {"data": "email"},
                                {"data": "active"},
                                {"data": "admin"}
                            ]
                        });
                    })
                    .fail(function (e) {
                        console.log('error', e);
                    });
};
```

When I execute this, I get the error: DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Invalid JSON response.
When I check my json response in F12 -> network with jsonlint it says that this is valid json, so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here.

This is what I've tried before, but when I add or delete or update a user, something goes wrong with reloading the table, which I do after each delete, add or update function. It just gives me all users, where it should give 10 with pagination, and when I sort them it still seems to use old data.

```
$.getJSON('/admin/users3/qryUsers')
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log('data', data);
                    // Clear tbody tag
                    $('tbody').empty();
                    // Loop over each item in the array
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        let tr = '';
                        if (value.name === "Amber Akkermans") {
                            tr = `<tr>
                           <td>${value.id}</td>
                           <td>${value.name}</td>
                           <td>${value.email}</td>
                           <td>${value.active}</td>
                           <td>${value.admin}</td>
                           <td>
                           <form action="/admin/users3/${value.id}" method="post" class="deleteForm">
@method('delete')
                            @csrf
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-edit"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        data-user="${value.name}"
                            data-id="${value.id}"
                            data-email="${value.email}"
                            data-active="${value.active}"
                            data-admin="${value.admin}"
                            title="Edit ${value.name}" disabled>
                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-delete"
                            data-toggle="tooltip"
                            data-user="${value.name}"
                            data-id="${value.id}"
                            title="Delete ${value.name}" disabled>
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                </form>
        </td>
           </tr>`;
                        } else {
                            tr = `<tr>
               <td>${value.id}</td>
               <td>${value.name}</td>
               <td>${value.email}</td>
               <td>${value.active}</td>
               <td>${value.admin}</td>
               <td>
               <form action="/admin/users3/${value.id}" method="post" class="deleteForm">
@method('delete')
                            @csrf
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-edit"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        data-user="${value.name}"
                            data-id="${value.id}"
                            data-email="${value.email}"
                            data-active="${value.active}"
                            data-admin="${value.admin}"
                            title="Edit ${value.name}">
                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-delete"
                            data-toggle="tooltip"
                            data-user="${value.name}"
                            data-id="${value.id}"
                            title="Delete ${value.name}">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                </form>
        </td>
           </tr>`;
                        }
                        $('tbody').append(tr);
                    });
                    $('#table_id').DataTable();
                })
                .fail(function (e) {
                    console.log('error', e);
                })
        }
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Return response()-json($var)

Comment: Still gives same error, do I have to change something in my loadtable function too?

Comment: Show response which you are getting

Comment: Sorry I fixed it already, I adjusted my datatable syntax a bit and used '/admin/users3/qryUsers' as url: $('#table_id').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '/admin/users3/qryUsers',
                    dataSrc: ''
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'name'},
                    {data: 'email'},
                    {data: 'active'},
                    {data: 'admin'},

Answer (score 0):

to return information to the format json.
change qryUsers function to :

```
    public function qryUsers()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('name')
            ->get();
        return response()->json($users);
    }
```